# Run-time Error for macro when protecting cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

First of all, I am very new to writing macros so the solution here might be very obvious but here is my problem:

I have this bit of code here that I got with the help of a user here on Stack Overflow a short while ago that was working really well up until I started running into some issues. The code is designed to protect a cell after data has been entered in that cell on a particular sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    With Me
        ''unprotect for VBA only
        .Protect Password:="mypassword", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
        ''unlock entire column
        .Range("A:A").Locked = False

        ''lock only filled cells
        InverseRange(.Range("A2:A" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count), .Range("A2:A" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)).Locked = True
    End With

End Sub

Function InverseRange(rFull As Range, rPart As Range) As Range
    Dim tmp As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In rFull.Cells
        If Intersect(cel, rPart) Is Nothing Then
            If tmp Is Nothing Then
                Set tmp = cel
            Else
                Set tmp = Union(tmp, cel)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Set InverseRange = tmp
End Function
```

The code runs perfectly until you get past the 17th cell ***but only if*** there is content in the first cell. If the first cell is empty you can go as far down as you want without issue but as soon as you enter data into the first cell and try to add something to a cell below 17 the script crashes and gives a "Run-time error":

[image: Error Message]

Comment: This is probably due to `SpecialCells` and `UsedRange`: No cells --> Error 1004 on SpecialCells

Comment: Couple of things... Change `Set InverseRange = tmp` to `If Not tmp is nothing then Set InverseRange = tmp Else Set InverseRange = Nothing` and then store `InverseRange(.Range("A2:A" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count), .Range("A2:A" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks))` in a range object say `rng` and then use `If not rng is nothing then rng.Locked = True`

Comment: Thanks @SiddharthRout but I am pretty new to working with macros. I followed that first part but how would I create a range object?

Comment: You'd declare a `Range` variable, and then assign it: `Dim rng As Range`, and then `Set rng = InverseRange(.Range("A2:A" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count), .Range("A2:A" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks))`

Comment: give it a try as @MathieuGuindon suggested. if you are still not able to get it, i will post a reply but i want you to try it first :)